# Splitting a timestamp in Matlab

Tags: matlab, textscan

I have a file with a data value and timestamp that I am trying to split in Matlab.
This is the format:

```
-18.151346    Mon Jan 28 11:33:08 2013
```

I am using the textscan function to try and split it.

```
data=textscan(fid,'%f%s%s%f%s%n','delimiter','space');
```

I am trying to split the timestamp into separate columns so that I can just use the time and not the date or year. I had a look at some previous questions which were very similar but for some reason I just can't get it to do what I want. My resulting cell array is in this format.

```
Column 1     Column 2   Column 3 
-18.151346   Mon       Jan 28 11:33:08 2013
```

I am completely new to Matlab so any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You're using a `'space'` string as a delimiter, which is illegal in `textscan`. Specify it as `' '` instead.
2. You want treat consecutive spaces as one, so you should also set the `'MultipleDelimsAsOne'` flag to 1.

The correct syntax should be:

```
textscan( fid, '%f%s%s%s%s%n', 'delimiter', ' ', 'MultipleDelimsAsOne', 1);
```

Had you not tried to tinker with the delimiter option, this behavior would've been done properly by default, so just omit all options:

```
textscan( fid, '%f%s%s%s%s%n');
```

Also note that you need a flag for each item in the string that is surrounded by spaces. In other words, for a string like this:

> -18.151346    Mon Jan 28 11:33:08 2013

the timestamp in string form will be stored in the 5th column of the resulting cell array.

Comment: +1: Also, the asterisk can be used to ignore columns, so using `'%*f %*s %*s %*s %*s %*n'` as a format string allows you to extract only the time.

Comment: Using the format you provided (and various other combinations) leaves me with the same output as before. Using the asterisk to try and isolate the time just leaves me with a blank data table. My second column reads 'Mon J' so its as if its not recognizing the space as the delimiter?

Comment: @Bob you specified the delimiter incorrectly, please refer to the revised answer. Also, forgive me for putting an extra asterisk in the format string, use this instead: `'%*f %*s %*s %*s %s %*n'`. I have tested it and it works now.

Comment: Yes! Omitting all the options works perfectly, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

To read the timestamp I'd use `regexp`.

The solution I'm gonna advise can be optimized, but it can help you at least as first try.

```
A = regexp(str,'[^\s]+','match');
```

This way you match all the regular expressions within your string. Then, you know that `values` and `time` are stored as element 1 and 5.

I made a short test with:

```
cell = {'-18.151346 Mon Jan 28 11:33:08 2013','19.33333 Tue Feb 29 10:12:23 2012'};
```

and this leads you to a cell `A{1,2}`.

Again, this procedure is perfectible, but you can use it as hint.

Comment: This might work. 
I need to plot the value (-18.151346) against the time (11:33:08) so is there a way of extracting both at once.
Also, that one column is part of a results file with 1440 entries so what would be the easiest way to process all of them at once. If I create a cell array with all the data and then covert it to a matrix and call it out one line at a time would that work? Or is there an easier way?

Comment: do the values have a standard number of digits?

Comment: I'm using the first solution as it fits better with what I am trying to do. Thanks for your input though.